# dkan resource not saving

Tags: 7

I have Drupal 7 using the DKAN module. When I edit a resource and try to save it, I'm getting a The URL is invalid error message.

Here is the url that is being edited from: http://hostname/?q=dataset/datasetnet/resource/e1f740cd-e80c-40d7-8d5d-e5a7221afe7c and then url change to http://hostname/?q=node/2051/edit.

So I checked the log and here is what I'm seeing the following errors:

Notice: Undefined index: filefield_dkan_remotefile in dkan_dataset_resource_node_form_validate() (line 536 of /dkan/dkan/profiles/dkan/modules/dkan/dkan_dataset/dkan_dataset.forms.inc).

Is there a reason why the resource is not saving?

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: i'm not sure, but i would recommend asking in the DKAN issues found at Github where they actively develop their modules. The DKAN set of modules on github can be found at https://github.com/NuCivic/dkan

Comment: I asked that question there and they don't know.